# How to stop method execution within specific given timeout (5 second) in Java?

Tags: java

It is possible to terminate method execution or we can specify the method timeout. Actually I have a requirement, if I give timeout for method that should be completed in given specific time if not then terminate method execution.

Comment: Hi Ravi and welcome to stackoverflow! Can you add your code ? On stackoverflow you have to show what you've done for other people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, how to terminate method execution within give time.

```
class TimerTask implements Runnable{
private FTPClient client;
public static FTPFile[] files;

public TimerTask(FTPClient client) {
    this.client=client;
    files=null;
    System.out.println("client is Connected: "+client.isConnected());
}
@Override
public void run() {
    PacketHandler tcph = new PacketHandler();
    files=tcph.getFiles(client); // custom get files method(-)
}
}
```

write another method where you want to use this.

```
public void myService(){    
final ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        boolean timeoutFlag=true;
        FTPFile[] files=null;
        TimerTask st= new TimerTask(client);

        try {
            final Future<TimerTask> f =  (Future<TimerTask>) service.submit(st);
            f.get(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // give here the execution time in 6 seconds 
            System.out.println("count files:"+TimerTask.files.length);
            files=TimerTask.files;
        } catch (final TimeoutException e) {
            timeoutFlag=false;
            Print.logInfo("Timeout exception..");
            System.out.println("Timeout exception");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            timeoutFlag=false;
            Print.logInfo("Timeout exception : "+e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("timeout exception "+e.getMessage() );
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this can count how much time start from execution.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
int timeExec = 5;
while( ( System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 ) - startTime < timeExec){
    //TODO
}
```

**Edit:**

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {

     summ();

}


public static void summ() {

    int i = 0;

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    int timeExec = 2;
    while( ( System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 ) - startTime < timeExec){

        i++;

    }

    System.out.println(i);

}
```

Comment: if i call my method in while() loop, the method will call 5 times but i want when 5 second is completed then terminate execution. and method call should be only once.

Comment: add this while in your method. not where you call it. I will come back with an edit.